is_number Function Implementation in C++
I am trying to implement a function which can determine a string is a number or not. Both positive and negative integers / floating numbers are considered.
The experimental implementation

is_number function implementation
bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    if(s.empty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool is_negative_number = false;
    bool output = false;
    if(s.starts_with("-"))
    {
        is_negative_number = true;
        if(is_number_helper(s.substr(1, s.size())) == false)
            return false;
        if(s.substr(1, 1) == ".")               //  deal with the case "-."
            return false;
        if(std::ranges::count(s, '.') > 1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    if(is_number_helper(s.substr(0, s.size())) == false)
        return false;
    if(s.substr(0, 1) == ".")                   //  deal with the case ".XXX"
        return false;
    if(std::ranges::count(s, '.') > 1)
        return false;
    return true;
}


is_number_helper function implementation
//  Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4654718/6667035
bool is_number_helper(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && (std::isdigit(*it) || *it == '.')) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}



Full Testing Code
The full testing code:
//  is_number Function Implementation in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>

//  Copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37264642/6667035
#ifndef NDEBUG
#   define M_Assert(Expr, Msg) \
    __M_Assert(#Expr, Expr, __FILE__, __LINE__, Msg)
#else
#   define M_Assert(Expr, Msg) ;
#endif

void __M_Assert(const char* expr_str, bool expr, const char* file, int line, const char* msg)
{
    if (!expr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Assert failed:\t" << msg << "\n"
            << "Expected:\t" << expr_str << "\n"
            << "Source:\t\t" << file << ", line " << line << "\n";
        abort();
    }
}

//  Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4654718/6667035
bool is_number_helper(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && (std::isdigit(*it) || *it == '.')) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}

bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    if(s.empty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool is_negative_number = false;
    bool output = false;
    if(s.starts_with("-"))
    {
        is_negative_number = true;
        if(is_number_helper(s.substr(1, s.size())) == false)
            return false;
        if(s.substr(1, 1) == ".")               //  deal with the case "-."
            return false;
        if(std::ranges::count(s, '.') > 1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    if(is_number_helper(s.substr(0, s.size())) == false)
        return false;
    if(s.substr(0, 1) == ".")                   //  deal with the case ".XXX"
        return false;
    if(std::ranges::count(s, '.') > 1)
        return false;
    return true;
}

void is_number_test()
{
    M_Assert(
        is_number("") == false,
        "Empty string test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("123") == true,
        "123 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("123.123") == true,
        "123.123 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("-123") == true,
        "-123 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("-123.123") == true,
        "-123.123 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("0") == true,
        "0 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("-0") == true,
        "-0 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("2147483647") == true,
        "2147483647 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("-2147483648") == true,
        "-2147483648 test case failed");

    //  values from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48650578/6667035
    M_Assert(
        is_number("-340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0000000000000000") == true,
        "-340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0000000000000000 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0000000000000000") == true,
        "340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0000000000000000 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("-179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.0000000000000000") == true,
        "-179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.0000000000000000 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.0000000000000000") == true,
        "179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.0000000000000000 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("-.123") == false,
        "-.123 test case failed");

     M_Assert(
        is_number("-ABC.123") == false,
        "-ABC.123 test case failed");
     
     M_Assert(
        is_number("-123.123.") == false,
        "-123.123. test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("-123..") == false,
        "-123.. test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("--123") == false,
        "--123 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number("-12-3") == false,
        "-12-3 test case failed");

    M_Assert(
        is_number(".123") == false,
        ".123 test case failed");
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    is_number_test();
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << '\n';
    return 0;
}

The output of the test code above:
Computation finished at Wed May  1 08:57:30 2024
elapsed time: 1.1501e-05

Godbolt link is here.
All suggestions are welcome.

When you decide to use an answer, read the comments. In this case, they pointed out a minor flaw.

You can make it constexpr
You can make both functions constexpr, ensuring you can do compile-time checking of strings for valid numbers.
Use std::string_view
Use std::string_view instead of const std::string&; it can avoid converting string literals to std::strings.
Enable compiler warnings and fix them
My compiler is complaining that is_negative_number and output are both unused variables. You should remove them.
What is a valid "number"?
Your function only accepts a subset of what are usually considered valid numbers in most programming languages. Here are some examples of numbers that your code doesn't consider valid, but are accepted by C++ and Python:

" 1 ": leading and trailing space
"+1": leading + sign as opposed to the - sign
".1": omitting the leading 0 in floating point numbers
"6.6e-34": scientific notation
"0xC0FFEE": hexadecimal numbers (they even come in floating point!)
"NAN", "INF", "-INF": non-finite floating point numbers
Combinations of the above

There are also some strings your function thinks are valid numbers, but most programming languages would disagree:

"08": a leading 0 often indicates an octal number, but 8 is not a valid octal digit

I strongly suggest that you either make it accept all the number formats that C++ accepts (either as literals, or using library functions such as std::scanf(), std::stod() and std::from_chars()), or else make it absolutely clear that you only accept a particular form of numbers.
If you want to validate strings containing numbers, it helps if you know what code will actually process those strings. For example, if that code calls std::stod(), you probably want your validator to follow the same rules as std::stod().

Thank you for answering > "08": a leading 0 often indicates an octal number I tried std::stod("08") and it returns "8" without problem.

@JimmyHu You have to understand the difference in where and how numbers are presented. The compiler 'saw' the expression you tested as a string containing two digits, so that string was passed to the function for conversion. Try "\08". Here, the compiler will try to translate those 3 characters to an octal value during compilation... and will emit an error message: failed to convert to octal... Try int x = 08; to get similar (erroneous) results. Don't take the expression shown as text in this answer to be LITERALLY a string. You have to think about how values are expressed.

isdigit() expects an int that can be represented as an unsigned char or EOF:
From std::isdigit:

Like all other functions from <cctype>, the behavior of std::isdigit
is undefined if the argument's value is neither representable as
unsigned char nor equal to EOF. To use these functions safely with
plain chars (or signed chars), the argument should first be converted
to unsigned char.

So:
std::isdigit(*it)

should be:
std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it))

Chain consecutive conditions:
if(s.starts_with("-"))
{
    is_negative_number = true;
    if(is_number_helper(s.substr(1, s.size())) == false)
        return false;
    if(s.substr(1, 1) == ".")               //  deal with the case "-."
        return false;
    if(std::ranges::count(s, '.') > 1)
        return false;
    return true;
}
if(is_number_helper(s.substr(0, s.size())) == false)
    return false;
if(s.substr(0, 1) == ".")                   //  deal with the case ".XXX"
    return false;
if(std::ranges::count(s, '.') > 1)
    return false;
return true

can be written as:
if(s.starts_with("-"))
{
    is_negative_number = true;
    return is_number_helper(s.substr(1, s.size()))
           && s.substr(1, 1) != "."             //  deal with the case "-."
           && std::ranges::count(s, '.') <= 1;
}

return is_number_helper(s.substr(0, s.size()))
       && s.substr(0, 1) != "."                 //  deal with the case ".XXX"
       && std::ranges::count(s, '.') <= 1;

I don't see where is_negative_number is used in the code, and the code would be even shorter if you use it:
bool is_negative_number = s.starts_with("-");

return is_number_helper(s.substr(is_negative_number, s.size()))
           && s.substr(is_negative_number, 1) != "."            //  deal with the case "-."/".XXX" 
           && std::ranges::count(s, '.') <= 1;

§4.7/4 from the C++ 11 or 14 Standard, §7.8/4 from the C++ 17 Standard, §7.3.9/2 from the 20 Standard says (Integral Conversion):

If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and
the value true is converted to one.

Do not prefix identifiers with underscores:
Identifiers preceded with adjacent/double underscores are reserved for the implementation in both C and C++.
(§17.6.4.3.2):

Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to
the implementation:
— Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an
underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the
implementation for any use.
— Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the
implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

See: What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?.
In the absence of an explicit return statement at the end of main, return 0/EXIT_SUCCESS is implicitly returned:
So you can do away with return 0.
Hide the definition of the main() function with a macro:
This translation unit can be included in another one if we do:
#ifdef TEST_MAIN

// define main

#endif    /* TEST_MAIN */

Or you could use NDEBUG instead. Now to have main() visible, define TEST_MAIN or pass it as a flag to the compiler.
